# Apache Camel Schedule multiple times a day

Tags: java, cron, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I have to execute/run same task in different fixed times every day. The intervals between the time is not same.

for example I want to run a router 05:30, 11:30, 15:00, 21:00.

I got lot of apache camel example with scheduler, quartz. But all are with static time interval or only one time configurable.

Is there way to configure in apache camel ?

Comment: Did you mean to tag `cron`?  This sort of thing is trivial to set up in your crontab, but your question text is asking about camel.

Comment: OP could actually use Camel's Quartz component with a `cron` configuration to do what he wants, but I have a feeling he doesn't know the proper cron expression to achieve this (nor do I off the top of my head).

Comment: Yes. I didn't get proper cron expression/configuration to use in Camel's Quartz.

Comment: You can not express this with a single Quartz cron expression. You can create a simple route for every time of the day you need to trigger an action, then simply call the route containing your actual logic from the trigger-routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<route>
  <from uri="quartz2://timer1?cron=0+30+5+*+*+*">
  <from uri="quartz2://timer2?cron=0+30+11+*+*+*">
  <from uri="quartz2://timer3?cron=0+00+15+*+*+*">
  <from uri="quartz2://timer4?cron=0+00+21+*+*+*">
  <to uri="...">
</route>
```

It's not possible today in the quartz component to provide a custom trigger, and the quartz cron trigger didn't support what you want. Just create a route with multiple consumers.